# how to creat a mathematic menu in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I had write a menu code in Tkinter which includes 2 mathematics programs.Each of these two programs run separately without any problems,but if you run this program it doesn't show anything in the result label.Please help me to solve this problem.

```
from tkinter import *
def case37():
    def cal37():
        number=int(e37.get())
        sumation=0
        for i in range(1,number+1):
            sumation+=1/(2**(i-1))
        result_var.set(sumation)
    
    window=Tk()

    Label(window,text='this is a series:').grid(row=0,column=0)
    Label(window,text='S=1,1/2,1/4,1/8,...').grid(row=0,column=1)
    Label(window,text='enter number of statement?').grid(row=1,column=0)
    label=Label(window,text='result:')
    label.grid(row=3,column=0)

    e37=Entry(window)
    e37.grid(row=1,column=1)

    Button(window,text='calculate',command=cal37,padx=10).grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)

    result_var=StringVar()
    result=Label(window,textvariable=result_var)
    result.grid(row=3,column=1)
    window.mainloop()


window=Tk()
window.geometry('300x400')
menubar=Menu(window)

filemenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label='calculate',menu=filemenu)

series=Menu(filemenu,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_cascade(label='series',menu=series)
series.add_command(label='example 2-37',command=case37)


window.config(menu=menubar)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` inside `case37()`.